# Printing between indexes in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a list of numbers which I pulled from a csv file and I want to print numbers 1-5, this is the code I wrote

```
print(winner_data[0], winner_data[1], winner_data[2], winner_data[3], winner_data[4])
```

is there any way of writing it shorter like

```
print(winner_data[0]-[4])
```

or something of the sort?

Comment: `winner_data[0:5]`?

Answer (score 0):

You directly use slicing for getting a subsection of any iterable.
`print(winner_data[0:5])`

For further info look up:

> Slicing in python.